# PHP Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object

Tags: php, class, public

```
class aa
{
    public $bb = false;
    public function display_box()
    {
        $this->bb = true;
    }
}

$cc = new aa;
$cc->display_box();
```

Yields this warning:

> [Debug] PHP Warning: in file rating.php on line 6: Attempt to assign
>   property of non-object

Comment: [norepro](https://eval.in/480917)

Comment: Which is line 6? Because this snippet of code has no errors

Comment: @bassxzero nope, makes no difference.

Comment: I see no error. What is file rating.php? And where its line 6?